# Using latest version of Xcode 8, support and test on for iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have been searching for an answer for this for a while now and I can't seem to get a straight answer anywhere. I'm new to iOS development and am looking to get started porting my android app over to make my first iOS app. I'm not a big apple user, so I'm just running xcode in a VM and trying to build and test on my old ipod touch 3rd generation running iOS 5.1.1. I understand how out of date this is, but I want to develop and test on this device for 2 reasons:

1. I dont want to buy a $750 new apple product just to test my very simple app
2. When I publish my app, I want to reach the most users possible

So my question is this:

1. In xcode 8, is it possible to develop applications with a deployment target of iOS 5.1.1?
2. If so, will it build for all versions of iOS?
3. When I attach my ipod to xcode, it says device is not supported, can I fix this by installing some 5.1.1 developer package or sdk to allow support? Or would I have to build, then manually install and test each iteration?
4. If all of these are possible, and I build an app targeted to 5.1.1, can I publish it to the app store? If I open the app store on my 5.1.1 ipod, there are still apps in the store with recent update dates, so people must still be releasing updates to apps on iOS 5.1.1 right? Or am I missing something and an app that runs on iOS 5.1.1 is entirely banned by Apple.

A lot of questions, but If possible I really want to do this. Even getting a fully known, confirmed answer for ANY of these questions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try to find an ancient Xcode that supports that iOS version. That's basically the only way. And hope that it produces a package that Apple allows to be sent to the AppStore.

Comment: You need a newer Apple device and a newer iOS version - full stop. Apple is dropping support for developing for 32-bit devices. If you want to test an app on an Apple device or ship on the App Store then you MUST use a 64-bit device. No 64-bit devices will support iOS 5.1.1 so you must also develop against a newer iOS SDK; don't bother developing against anything less than the current 10.3 for a new app. All this is well documented if you do an internet search.

Comment: You can get started by testing on the simulator rather than a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want to buy a $750 new apple product just to test my very
>   simple app

Xcode has a simulator, you don't need a device to test your app.

> When I publish my app, I want to reach the most users possible

As of July 31th 2017, https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

- 86% of devices are using iOS 10.
- 11% of devices are using iOS 9.
- 3% of devices are using earlier. (probably iOS 8)

It makes sense that you have this concern coming from Android, but iOS is quite different. Devices are designed to be uniform and apple encourages (almost forces) people to update them. (You won't stop receiving a notification to update your device)

It would actually be bad to focus on developing for that specific device you have, specially because a lot of the APIs will be deprecated, plus the screen ratio of that specific device is not so common.

> In xcode 8, is it possible to develop applications with a deployment
>   target of iOS 5.1.1?

No*

> If so, will it build for all versions of iOS?

Kind of, it will run but it won't probably be what you expect until you FIX it for that specific iOS version. (many things break between iOS updates so developers are sometimes forced to branch code)

> When I attach my ipod to xcode, it says device is not supported, can I
>   fix this by installing some 5.1.1 developer package or sdk to allow
>   support? Or would I have to build, then manually install and test each
>   iteration?

Maybe, but probably not. You can actually copy files from older xcodes to enable testing in newer ones. You can search about how to do this by googling for "Using iOS 7 in Xcode 8". However I doubt going as far back as iOS 5 will be possible. The Xcode needed for running on iOS 5 is not even supported macOS Sierra (The newest OS)

> If all of these are possible, and I build an app targeted to 5.1.1,
>   can I publish it to the app store? If I open the app store on my 5.1.1
>   ipod, there are still apps in the store with recent update dates, so
>   people must still be releasing updates to apps on iOS 5.1.1 right? Or
>   am I missing something and an app that runs on iOS 5.1.1 is entirely
>   banned by Apple.

Theoretically yes, iOS Apps can still "support" old iOS version, the reason why developers drop support for older os is because it gets increasingly hard to debug them as well as they just don't have support for new features and APIs that come with newer iOS.

My suggestion if you are really obsessed with building for iOS 5.1.1 is to ensure it's a 64 bit app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html

And Download an old version of Xcode: (Maybe Xcode 7 or 6?)

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

But I think you still have to Build with xcode 8 since you need to build against their latest SDK. The old Xcode is just to develop for it and facilitate debugging.